# User account pool creation encountered failure while executing the registerRext.exe in SQL server 2016 R services

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, revolution-r, rro

[the cmd execution of registerRExt.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2j7a.png)

I am trying to install RRE(Revolution R Enterprise) v7.5 with RR0 3.2.2(Revolution R Open) on a SQL Server 2016 RC0 default instance. All the steps shown in the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590808.aspx have been completed and the error occurs in the Post installation Server configuration scripts. The script has also been replaced by the updated script for RC0 shown on the msdn site but still I get the same error on running the registerRExt.exe file. 
The site shows while installing the instance the account name for Server Database engine has to be MSSQLSERVER, however this had also resulted in an error stating wait on database recovery handle failed which was sorted by changing the account name of Database engine to NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM(I provided this info as it can also be the cause of the problem) . Now I need to sort the user pool failure. Any help would be appreciated..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort out the issue..It was because I was installing the SQL server on domain controller and ignored the warning while install, but then changing some rules and demoting it from Server Manager worked and the install was successful.

However I do know there may be some better solution to that as all the other user accounts got reset in the process.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2016 RC1 was just released https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/18/sql-server-2016-release-candidate-1-now-available/.

SQL RC1 has a newer version 8.0.1 version of RRE. I suggest your try to install it and reply to this thread again if you hit the same failure. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt590809.aspx has the details on where to find Microsoft R Open 8.0.1 and Revolution R Enterprise 8.0.1.

If the issue persists **RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\registerrext.log** would have more details on the exact failure - do share that.

Comment: I tried SQL RC1 with RRE 8.0.1..Still the same issue..here is the [log file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1EDF1A02DBB617AE!72196&authkey=!ALggpm5nO86iV70&ithint=file%2ctxt) also i had to install Database engine with account name NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM as it had the same error while installing the SQL 2016 RC1 server.